# How to solve error during aws cli get-session-token?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I am trying to refresh my session token under IAM profile with MFA authentification:

```
aws sts get-session-token
--duration-seconds $DURATION
--serial-number $AWS_SERIAL
--token-code $AWS_MFA  ~/.aws/cli/cache/session.json
```

But, I got this error:

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetSessionToken operation: Cannot call GetSessionToken with session credentials
```

My ARN is as below:

```
  arn;aws:sts;XXXXX:assumed-role/YYYYYY/botoscore-session-ZZZZ
```

I looked over internet and were not able to find correct solution.
Is there any direction that I should look.

Comment: AWS STS temporary credentials cannot be extended or refreshed beyond the original specified interval. You need to create a new set of credentials.

Comment: Any AWS CLI example ?

Comment: Example of generating new sts token?

Comment: The linked duplicate Question explains your situation. Basically, you can't call `get-session-token` from an IAM Role. You can only call it when using IAM User credentials. From [get-session-token — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/2.1.30/reference/sts/get-session-token.html): _"The `GetSessionToken` operation must be called by using the long-term AWS security credentials of the AWS account **root user or an IAM user.**"_

Comment: Did you originally run `get-session-token` against IAM User credentials, and now you want a new set of temporary credentials because the first ones have expired? If so, make sure you run `get-session-token` against the IAM User credentials, not the temporary credentials. I suspect that you might have taken the result of the first `get-session-token` and stored them as Environment Variables? If so, then the AWS CLI is using them instead of your IAM User credentials. You should remove those Environment Credentials before requesting new temporary credentials.

Answer (score 0):

From AWS documentation:-

> Temporary credentials expire after a specified interval. After
> temporary credentials expire, any calls that you make with those
> credentials will fail, so you must generate a new set of temporary
> credentials. **Temporary credentials cannot be extended or refreshed
> beyond the originally specified interval.**

References:-

- [Using temporary credentials with AWS resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_use-resources.html)
- [get-session-token](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/get-session-token.html)
- [aws sts get-session-token fails with profile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55468397/12326605)

Hope it helps.